# 'data-*' not working on HTML5 in Microsoft Expression Web

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I was learning 'data-*' in jQuery using Microsoft Expression Web 4 but I couldn't insert data- inside my MEE4. I was using XHTML1.1 before but then I have already changed the setting to HTML5 and yet when I typed in data- inside my  tag, an error which says: "in HTML 5 the attribute 'data-button1' is not permitted for the  tag".

This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    <link href="css/stylestesting.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">

    <style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
text-align: right;
  }
     </style>
  </head>

    <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1 id="main">Let's Have Fun!</h1>


    <div id="button">

            <button id="btn1" data-panel="btn5">#btn1</button>
            <button id="btn2" data-button1="btn5">#btn2</button>
            <button id="btn3" data-button1="btn5">#btn3</button>
            <button id="btn4" data-button1="btn5">#btn4</button>

    </div>

    <div id="button1">

            <button id="btn5">
            <div class="auto-style1">
                #btn5</div>
            </button>
            <button id="btn6">#btn6</button>
            <button id="btn7">#btn7</button>
            <button id="btn8">#btn8</button>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="jquery-3.1.0%20(1).js"></script>
<script src="js/ForTesting.js"></script>
```

Comment: in strict version of HTML it won't allow custom attributes while parsing the document

Comment: If you don't get an answer to your question and create a new one trargeting the same question then you should link to it ([Error using 'data-*' in Microsoft Expression HTML 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701311)) and explain why you opened a new one. Beside that I would guess that _Microsoft Expression Web_  does not fully support html5.